# How to copy current path from nautilus in 19.04 using keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, nautilus, 19.04

I recently upgraded to Ubuntu 19.04 from 18.10 and the usual way of copying the current path by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>l</kbd> and then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> does not work. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>l</kbd> does select the current path but <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> does not copy the path. Pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> loses the focus.

I am using GNOME nautilus 3.32.0.

Comment: cannot reproduce, same version. Ctrl+l + Ctrl+c works well.

Comment: @RoVo Should I re-install nautilus?

Comment: dunno actually.

Comment: @DKBose Preferably not. Just the path to the current directory I am in.

Comment: @DKBose Thanks for your comment but I have invested a lot of time (around half a day) to set up my new system. But can I rename _~/.config.bak_ again  _~/.config_ to gain my system as it is now?

Comment: @DKBose I do not see the `.config` file in my home folder even when I have enabled hidden folders but entering `~/.config` in nautilus path takes me to the `.config` folder. `cd "~/.config"` in terminal outputs `No such file or directory`. Strange.

Comment: It's a folder, not a file. If you're in the home folder in the terminal use just `cd .config`.

Comment: @DKBose Changing the config folder did not do any benefit. But I have figured that ctrl + l and ctrl + c is still workable of I keep the ctrl key pressed.